Does physical entropy matter for sustainability or economic prosperity?
This is an edit from a previous question, i hope i have polished it enough.
Working not in the field it is sometimes hard to understand concepts related to something so abstract as entropy, especially when related to sustainability and economy.
I will leave some reflections based on scientific facts or theories i came across even if sporadically in the hope that those who have a deeper understanding of the matter could clarify and connects dots better than i do, or even better provide some critical thinking about possible implication regarding entropy and sustainability.
According to this article
Entropy and Energy: Toward a Definition of Physical Sustainability
The link between entropy and sustainability it is not just possible but indeed it would give a better picture of the different physical processes since pure matter or energy accounting methods would miss the complete picture. According to the article the lower the entropy and energy related to a process the bigger the sustainability.
Even if this link open surely an interesting perspective on a theoretical level, because the mere co2 footprint calculation sounds quite rough most of the time, i am not sure that on a practical level the actual entropy calculation would add much to the current methods of accounting ecological impact of a certain process, in the attempt to find solutions to urgent climatic issues.
There might be other ways in which entropy and sustainability are intertwined of which i am not aware. I wonder what are the main issues that we face when we are talking about sustainability beyond co2 accounting, because from my point of view, from one side it is true that decreasing co2 is quite the urgent problem to decrease global warming or slow it down, but in the longer term (maybe 100 years) or looking at the big picture, questions related to material resources availability and efficiency in energy production are quite important, and maybe new and more holistic methods are required to face more efficiently this problems.
Thanks in advance, I hope i clarified my question

Interesting idea, but I am skeptical just from seeing the claim that Shannon and Boltzmann entropies are the same. Indeed, Boltzmann entropy can be seen as a trivial case of Shannon entropy... but apart from that they are quite different animals. See here for more details.

I concur with @RogerV. on the different entropies, but with the nitpick that the Shannon entropy and the Gibbs entropy are functionally the same equation, whereas Boltzmann entropy and Gibbs entropy will disagree for small systems. They are indeed quite different animals.

As for the question as in the title, the difficulty is in making sure that whatever scheme you are doing, is able to avoid becoming impractical. I mean, it is obviously the case that entropy ought to say something about the various processes. However, outside of the physical-chemical processes that are so well-known that they can be textbook material, it is difficult to even ascribe entropy to complicated real-world processes. The article nicely provides a calculated example, but it could easily be too complicated to treat properly. Non-equilibrium stat therm is still being researched

That different ressources follow different cycles, have different time scales of reproduction, and that some can be depleted, while others are in continuous supply, is both well known and highly specific to the systems considered. In the context of economical sustainability, these systems are wide and complex, up to the scale of the planet and its solar input. Whole disciplines, which of course use physics, including what it has to say about energy and entropy, are dedicated to their study. I can't see what is conceptually new in the paper, or how its definition of sustainability is useful.

@naturallyInconsistent Not sure what your comment means. AFAIK, there are Gibbs I and Gibbs II - one is functionally the Shannon entropy, whereas the other is defined phenomenologically - that is it has nothing to do with Shannon. Boltzmannn entropy is just the number of states. It's mathematical form is a trivial case of Shannon... but where Shannon measures the inequality of probabilities, Boltzmann measures the number of states (the probabilities of which are all equal) and its functional dependence on parameters.
